# Dynamic SharePoint Navigation Link

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss, navigation, hyperlink

Inside of SharePoint under site settings >> look and feel >> Navigation you have the ability to throw down some link entries for navigation. My question is is there any simple way short of writing a feature, to somehow make the links dynamic so that they will append the query string of the current page that is being viewed?

Edit:
When you navigate to a web page the URL can have arguments, this is known as the query string. SharePoint is no different you can have URL's that you point your browser to along with a query string. The pages in SharePoint typically have a quick launch left nav area where it renders out a static list of pre-defined URL's. What I want to do is have these static links be dynamic in that they copy the query string and append it to the static url that I defined from the page that is currently being viewed which may or may not have a query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking for something that it's impossible. The only way you could do something of that is creating a new provider and configure it on the menu. This new provider could check some kinds of items in the Navigation option and returns the url you want it.